# How to properly return a list from a pytest fixture for use in parametrize?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, parametrized-testing

I am attempting to build a little pytest test to ensure all expected keys exist in redis. I have a list of expected keys, that I am storing as a YML file. The test itself will query against redis to ensure each of the expected keys from the list exists.

Initially, I had this set up as a giant list in the `test_keys.py` file. This was set up like so:

```
expected_keys = ['key1','key2','key3']
@pytest.mark.parametrize('expected_key', expected_keys)
def test_expected_key(expected_key):
    ...
```

This works. Since I want to replicate this type of test for a few other checks of the redis environment, I don't want to put multiple lists with a few hundred keys into these files.

I thought I could pull them out into YML files and load the keys via fixtures.

My fixture looks like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def expected_keys_fixture():
    with open('expected_keys.yml'), 'r') as f:
        return yaml.safe_load(f)['keys']
```

The YML looks like this:

```
keys:
  - key1
  - key2
  - key3
```

My test decorator changed to this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("expected_keys", [
    (pytest.lazy_fixture('expected_keys_fixture'))
])
def test_expected_key(expected_key):
    ...
```

I am using the [`pytest-lazy-fixture`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-lazy-fixture/) package for this.

The problem I have here is that `expected_keys` now equals the *entire* list of expected keys. It's no long each individual key like I had with the static list when it was in my test file.

I attempted to do as Oleh Rybalchenko [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56672356/1344579) suggested

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("expected_keys", pytest.lazy_fixture('expected_keys_fixture')
)
def test_expected_key(expected_key):
    ...
```

But, this fails with `TypeError: 'LazyFixture' object is not iterable`.

I understand I only have one argname and that I should have a list, but the example in the documentation is passing the parameters to the `fixture()` decorator. I am not. My list is being generated by the results of the YML file.

---

Question: How can I adjust my fixture so that it properly returned a single item at a time for the `parametrize` decorator?

Comment: Remove the list brackets in parametrize decorator?

Comment: Removing the list brackets results in `TypeError: 'LazyFixture' object is not iterable`

Comment: TBH I don't think your use case is solvable with `pytest-lazy-fixture`, looking at its sources. Keep in mind that this plugin is in its very early days and I doubt it's production ready. I don't see why you need it anyway - why not just read the file on module level? Or implement a custom `pytest_generate_tests` hook if your use case is more complex than described.

Answer (score 10):

In the same situation and the only way I found is to refuse the fixture and call the function directly.

```
def expected_keys_fixture():
    with open('expected_keys.yml', 'r') as f:
        return yaml.safe_load(f)['keys']


@pytest.mark.parametrize("expected_key",
                         expected_keys_fixture())
def test_expected_key(expected_key):
    assert expected_key in ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

Comment: It's my first time using pytest, and I had the same issue. I'm super surprised.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `params` parameter of the [`pytest.fixture` decorator](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference/reference.html#pytest.fixture) as shown in [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/fixtures.html#parametrizing-fixtures)

```
import pytest


def expected_keys():
    with open('expected_keys.yml', 'r') as f:
        return yaml.safe_load(f)['keys']


@pytest.fixture(params=expected_keys())
def expected_key(request):
    yield request.param


def test_keys(expected_key):
    assert expected_key in ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, pytest do not let you returning a list of possible test cases. So, I would implement a test loop.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('expected_key', expected_keys)
def test_expected_keys(expected_keys):
    for expected_key in expected_keys:
        test_expected_key()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that fixtures are executed *after* collecting tests, so it's not possible to multiply you tests from fixture result. But you can dynamically parametrize your test with [`pytest_generate_tests` hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example).

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in a similar problem once. I used the pytest global variable, pytest-fixures and pytest-mark-parametrize.

For the use above use-case following code should work fine.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def expected_key(request):
    """Create tester object"""
    return request.param

def expected_keys_fixture():
    with open('expected_keys.yml'), 'r') as f:
        return yaml.safe_load(f)['keys']

pytest.expected_keys = expected_keys_fixture()

@pytest.mark.parametrize('expected_key', pytest.expected_keys, indirect=True)
def test_expected_key(expected_key):
    condition = True # Change as per the use case
    assert condition

@pytest.mark.parametrize('expected_key', pytest.expected_keys, indirect=True)
def test_expected_key_2(expected_key):
    condition_2 = True # Change as per the use case
    assert condition

@pytest.mark.parametrize('expected_key', pytest.expected_keys, indirect=True)
def test_expected_key_3(expected_key):
    condition_3 = True # Change as per the use case
    assert condition
```

The main advantage of defining a Pytest global variable is that you don't have to repeatedly call the function expected_keys_fixture() for each kind of test case. Once the variable is defined, it can be used in multiple kinds of test cases without being reinitialised.